# applying CSS to ul > li

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently using multisites in WP and I am applying minor changes on individual sites instead of the whole network by using Custom CSS plugin.

In our website, nav menu's sub menu consists of two columns but I want to make it 1 column. In chrome **inspector** I am able to do that easily but however when I am trying to apply it in CSS nothing changes. I am sure that I am doing mistake in linking the div classes and other elements. What I am doing basically is copying the classes name in the inspector and pasting to Custom CSS plugin. Like below

This is the set of classes that I copied from inspector. `.header-area .main-menu > ul > li .submenu-wrap ul`

```
.header-area.main-menu > ul > li .submenu-wrap ul{
   column-count:1;
}
```

but when I do this it does not process.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Use `!important` tag or try `.main-menu > ul > li .submenu-wrap ul` may be it will help you.

Comment: Hi Jennifer, you can find the html in this link https://jsfiddle.net/vysjh7m2/1/

Comment: Hi @Lokesh, I tried but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Can you share screenshot or link of that page to get the more clear picture?

Comment: Hi @Sudarsh, you can find the link in the first row of this example - https://jsfiddle.net/vysjh7m2/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.header-area .main-menu > ul > li .submenu-wrap ul{
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  column-count: 1;
}
```

or if that doesn't work try:

```
.header-area .main-menu > ul#menu-main-menu > li .submenu-wrap ul{
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  column-count: 1;
}
```

What might be happening is that the Custom CSS plugin is placing your new css in the document before the existing css. If that is the case your changes will be overwritten by the existing stylesheet because you are using the same selector. By adding the ID "#menu-main-menu" (just for example in your case) I have given your new selector a higher specificity so it therefore won't be overwritten by the original.

Note:

1. Does ".header-area" exist on the same element as your ".main-menu" ?
   because it is not there in your jsfiddle example. If not, remove it
   from your new css.
2. Check your document after you make the change and confirm in the
   inspector that the new css is actually being added to the document,
   regardless of whether it works or not. We need to confirm that the
   plugin actually works and renders to the page.

Comment: Hi Partypete25, thanks for your recommendation but that sample didnt work for me. .header-area also is in the html but i did not include into the example. Well, i checked the custom css shows in the inspector. Also, I have made other changes like .header-area color etc, it worked but when it get into different classes with sub classes, i got confused.

Comment: ok but for header-area is it in the same class as main-menu on the nav? like this: <nav class="header-area main-menu"> When you join class names without a space like .classA.classB it means that they are on the same element.  but if there is a space like .classA .classB it means .classB is a child of .classA

Comment: No its not, for header <div class="header-area wrapper"> for main menu <nav class="main-menu">, I think inspector took it because it under header-area div.

Comment: So i just checked you link - so i've updated my answer accordingly. "header-area" is not on the nav, so the css should have a space.

Comment: Hi Pattypete, I have tried that too but unfortunately it does not work. I have cleared computer cache server/hosting cache and also WP cache too. The current minor changes that I have made, are working perfectly but now I notice if I add more changes Custom CSS does not apply.